# What do you call a green-land right behind a sea-shore?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word to describe the green, nature-lively land that stands right behind a sand-covered sea-shore coast leading into an ocean. So in trying to picture what I am looking for: imagine the ocean and then next to the ocean is the sanded shore and then next to that imagine a natural growth of trees, etc.
What word might best fit this description?

I included a rather deplorable sketch of what I mean.
[image]

Any insight would be greatly appreciated

EDIT: I just found this image. As seen in it, it describes a "coast" as land *Near* or *next* to the sea, but I am looking for a more specific word which describes the actual green-land (with the trees and bushes) as seen in this newfound image:

[image]

Comment: Is there an Earth Sciences StackOverflow? Yes! [Earth Sciences.SE](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/). They would have a much better idea of what the technical term might be.

Comment: Are you intentionally excluding dunes with grasses as the drawing suggests?

Answer (score 8):

In oceanography and coastal ecology I know no single word but the phrase *coastal fringe* is often used of the vegetated land immediately beyond the reach of the tides, or indeed just in reach - as in the case of mangroves. It has the advantage that *fringe* suggests the disorder of a natural vegetation.

To give just one example:
"Ecological Effects of Nutrient Enrichment on a Coastal Fringe Mangrove Forest Mangrove Forest"

(https://core.ac.uk/reader/56698320)

Answer (score 2):

Not a single word, but you could call it [*strand vegetation*](http://oos.soest.hawaii.edu/pacific-rcc/Marshalls%20Agroforestry/site/strand-vegetation.php). Also read [this book about 'strand vegetation'.](https://books.google.com/books?id=KQ3SBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA208&lpg=PA208&dq=strand%20vegetation&source=bl&ots=HLEzcGvVLV&sig=ACfU3U2gDaSMr5rR3l6eS-Buu3IUIJpkWA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjx_oa_jY_sAhWPz4UKHR2SALMQ6AEwGXoECBYQAQ#v=onepage&q=strand%20vegetation&f=false)

There's also '[hinterland](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hinterland)' which means *the land behind the coast or the banks of a river, or an area of a country that is far away from cities*, but I don't think it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

### Beachfront flora

> **[flora](https://www.lexico.com/definition/flora)**
> *The plants of a particular region, habitat, or geological period.*

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beach#Manmade_erosion_and_accretion)

> **Beachfront flora** plays a major role in stabilizing the foredunes and preventing beach head erosion and inland movement of dunes. If flora with network root systems (creepers, grasses, and palms) are able to become established, **they provide an effective coastal defense** as they trap sand particles and rainwater and enrich the surface layer of the dunes, **allowing other plant species to become established.**

Answer (score 1):

Maritime forest. There are really cool ones off the coast of Georgia, US.

From Wikipedia, "an ocean coastal wooded habitat found on higher ground than dune areas within range of salt spray," some [maritime forests](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maritime_forest) include:

> Some places where maritime forests can be found are: Bald Head Island
> (North Carolina), Necochea (Argentina), Jekyll Island (Georgia), and
> on almost all barrier islands, such as the Currituck Banks Reserve[7]
> in the Outer Banks of North Carolina.

Not a single word.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Litoral is the technical ecosystem term

Comment: This ('the litoral/littoral zone') is broader, **on** or near the shore. It includes the foreshore and the intertidal zone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please use standard written English here, where declarative sentences not only begin with a capital letter but also end with a period / full stop.